# Do I need to set the timezone in a PHP script, if it is set in php.ini?

Tags: php, timezone

`phpinfo()` tells me that my timezone is properly set:

[image]

`date_default_timezone_get()` returns "Europe/Berlin". Since I'm on 5.4.35 this should return the ini option (see the [manual](http://php.net/manual/de/function.date-default-timezone-get.php)).

Do I still need to set the timezone, as PHP's warning tells me?

> **Strict Standards:** strtotime(): It is not safe to rely on the system's timezone settings. You are *required* to use the date.timezone setting or the date_default_timezone_set() function. In case you used any of those methods and you are still getting this warning, you most likely misspelled the timezone identifier. We selected 'Europe/Berlin' for 'CET/1.0/no DST' instead in **/your/skript.php** on line **249**

Comment: What value do you have in your php.ini for date.timezone setting?

Comment: `date_default_timezone_get()` returns "Europe/Berlin". Since I'm on 5.4.35 this should return the ini option.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, you should always set the timezone, even if it is set on the server. This is needed as your script may not always run on that server, and may throw errors if moved to a server with an unset timezone.

Generally a good option for timezones is UTC:

`date_default_timezone_set('UTC')`